# Need a reboot after a deployment with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, nginx, capistrano

I'm running a rails 3 application hosted on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS. I'm using Capistrano for the deployment and nginx + unicorn for the server.
My problem is that if I did a "cap deploy", my website displays the old code until I reboot my VPS. I check the current code on the server and it is the right one. I have already tried to restart nginx, but it doesn't work.
My deploy file (I followed the Railscast):

```
# deploy.rb

require "bundler/capistrano"
require 'new_relic/recipes'

server "188.165.145.167", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "neurones"
set :user, "neurones"
set :deploy_to, "/home/neurones/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/uploads}

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:khcr/neurones.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases
after "deploy:update", "newrelic:notice_deployment" # update new relic

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: `run "touch tmp/restart.txt"` ?

Comment: @khcr Please check if the pids of the unicorn processes change after deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem. 
Looking in the unicorn log (thanks Domon for the idea), I saw the error:

> error reloading config_file=/home/neurones/apps/neurones/current/config/unicorn.rb: Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)

I changed **unicorn_init.sh from**:

```
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
```

**to**

```
restart|reload)
  sig USR2 && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
```

Comment: Not that I've encountered an actual use case for using `reload` instead of `restart` while deploying Rails apps, but `reload` and `restart` are distinct. `reload` is triggered by the `HUP` signal, and `restart` is triggered by the `USR2` signal. It probably doesn't matter in most situations, but it is a good practice not to conflate them. [Unicorn signals](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html)

Comment: so you would differentiate a case for restart with a USR2 signal and a case for reload with a HUP signal in my code ?